# Using Tag to define transform for Material.SetVector

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, shader-graph

I have a shadergraph where I pass position of gameobject as a value. Below is the code I tried for that but I get NullReferenceException.

```
public Material m;
private Transform player;
private GameObject character = GameObject.FindWithTag("Character");

void MoveGrass()
{
    player = character.transform;
    m.SetVector("_PlayerPos", player.position);
}

private void OnDrawGizmos()
{
    MoveGrass();
}

private void Update() 
{
    MoveGrass();
}
```

Please, help me figure this out. I'm trying to make gameObjects interact with grass elements in the game, which I'm able to when I'm using Transform.position as value, but I want to make it happen using a Tag name of gameobjects to make it easier to use.

Comment: I assume the NullReferenceException because of `character`?   Probably because the object tagged `Character` doesn't exist yet?  (Using a field initializer suggests you're looking for it a little too early in the lifecycle.)

Comment: Hi Wyck, please let me know the right way to do it.

Comment: You can't do `private GameObject character = GameObject.FindWithTag("Character");` .. it should be `private GameObject character;` and then later `private void Start(){private character = GameObject.FindWithTag("Character");}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Gameobject.find in a start/awake function and recheck if it's null :

```
 public Material m;
    private Transform player; 
    private GameObject character;

    void Start()
    {
        character = GameObject.FindWithTag("Character");
    }

    void MoveGrass()
    {
        if (character!=null)    
        {         
            player = character.transform; 
            m.SetVector("_PlayerPosition", player.position);
        }
        else
        {
            character = GameObject.FindWithTag("Character");
        }
    }

    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        MoveGrass();
        
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        MoveGrass();
    }
```

(I suggest you get rid of player transform and use character transform directly):

```
public Material m;
private GameObject character;
    
void Start()
{
    character = GameObject.FindWithTag("Character");
}
    
void MoveGrass()
{
    if (character!=null)
    {
        m.SetVector("_PlayerPosition", character.transform.position);
    }
    else
    {
        character = GameObject.FindWithTag("Character"); 
    }
    
}
    
private void OnDrawGizmos()
{
    MoveGrass();
}
    
private void Update() 
{
    MoveGrass();
}
```

Comment: Hi Anas, Thanks for the swift response. I tried what you said but I'm getting the following Error: UnassignedReferenceException: The variable character of OnGrass has not been assigned.
You probably need to assign the character variable of the OnGrass script in the inspector.

Comment: are you sure the character gameobject is active and using the correct tag ?

Comment: It is active and the Tag name is correct

Comment: Add a character null check before changing the player transform 

check first answer the code its readable there

Comment: else I suggest you look at the first answer I edited it to no longer need a player transform, and you can change it directly to the character

Comment: Now I get a Warning: The referenced script (Unknown) on this Behaviour is missing!
Also there is no response from the grass object on interaction

Comment: Sorry it was a mistake on my end. Your Solution Works! Its supposed to be m.SetVector("_PlayerPos", character.transform.position); I entered the X value wrong

Comment: glad it did good luck